# Changing rest output in json format from snake case to camel case in react web app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, npm

Changing rest output in JSON format in which the keys are present in snake case and I need to convert it to camel case

I am developing a React Web app in which I call my API endpoint and it gives me response like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "goals_for": 0,
        "goals_against": 0,
        "points": 0
    }
]
```

So here I want to convert the Keys of my JSON rest output from snake case to camel case like this (`goals_for` -> `goalsFor`)

After conversion I need the output like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "goalsFor": 0,
        "goalsAgainst": 0,
        "points": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: You want to change the response before using it in your code? If so you'll need to intercept the data when you make an API call and change the response object. In order to change from snake_case to camelCase you'll have to create a function that does that. There are plenty if you search for it, so you don't need to make it again.

Comment: If you control the API, can you not change the JSON serialiser server side?

Answer (score 2):

```
const snakeCaseArray = [{
        "id": 1,
        "goals_for": 0,
        "goals_against": 0,
        "points": 0
    }]


 /*using lodash*/
 const camelCaseArray = snakeCaseArray.map(item=>{
    return Object.keys(item).map(key=>{ 
       const newKeyName = _.camelCase(key) /*---> lodash function*/
       return {[newKeyName]:item[key]}
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the entire key value pairs and pass all the keys to the function and create a new object in javascript by using this snake to camel case function

```
function snakeToCamel(your_Key){
    return your_Key.replace(/(\-\w)/g, function(m){return m[1].toUpperCase();});
}
```